# How to write relationship mutation in GraphQL using GRANDstack?

Tags: neo4j, graphql, grandstack

I am trying to create a relationship between to nodes in Neo4j using GraphQL. What should the mutation look like?

Schema shows it should look like this.

```
AddPersonRoll(
from: _PersonInput!
to: _RollInput!
): _AddPersonRollPayload
```

I tryed

```
mutation {
  AddPersonRoll(
    from: {
      id: "be91aaca-944d-49f7-b3fd-c89ad454d5ab"
    }
    to: {
        id: "8726255f-b6b6-4299-ba01-95f6d4ef2be7"
    }
  ) { 
    from {
      id
      name
    }

    to {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

And it worked.  But when I tried putting var into the query I got

```
{
  "error": "Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid name"
}
```

the code is

```
mutation AddPersonRoll($PersonInput: ID!, $RollInput: ID!){
  AddPersonRoll(
    from: {
      id: $PersonInput
    }
    to: {
        id: $RollInput
    }
  ) { 
    from {
      id
      name
    }

    to {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}


{
  "PersonInput": "3cc70aca-9e07-4bbd-acb2-92670b4d1b0d",
  "RollInput": "8726255f-b6b6-4299-ba01-95f6d4ef2be7"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this earlier today when I ran into a similar problem. Here is my working mutation:

```
const ADD_INCIDENT_USER = gql`
  mutation AddIncidentUser($from: ID!, $to: ID!) {
    AddIncidentUser(from: { id: $from }, to: { id: $to }) {
      from {
        id
      }
      to {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

so in your example you would want to change

```
mutation AddPersonRoll($PersonInput: ID!, $RollInput: ID!){
```

to

```
mutation AddPersonRoll($from: ID!, $to: ID!){
```